# Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, string

The error is at this line: if (strcmp(answer[i],ans[i]) == 0)
Sorry if this is a dumb question, I already looked through most of the old posts but cannot get an answer.

```
int main()
{
    int score=0;
    char answer[20]={'T','F','F','T','F','F','T','T','T','T','F','F','T','F','T','F','T','F','T','T'};
    char ans[20]={'F','T','F','T','F','F','T','T','F','T','F','F','T','F','T','F','T','F','T','T'};

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(answer[i],ans[i]) == 0)
        {
            score++;
            cout << "No. " << i+1 << " is correct!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "No. " << i+1 << "is false!" << endl;
        }   
    }
    cout << "Score: " << score << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `answer[i]` and `ans[i]` are chars, not strings. No need for `strcmp`. Just compare them: `if (answer[i] == ans[i]) ...`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp oh yeah you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use char instead of string so no need strcmp.
Just

```
if (answer[i] == ans[i])
```

Thanks! @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `strcmp`:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

It takes `char*` arguments and is designed to compare null terminated strings. You pass an argument of the wrong type `char`. In addition, the usage logic is violated - `strcmp` returns 0 if the contents of both strings are equal, so match checks `!strcmp(str1, str2)`. To compare two chars just do

```
 answer[i] == ans[i]
```